# How to get the scm connnectionurl from an external file into the pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I want to get the `connectionUrl` and other properties such as `modules` to checkout the repositories from an external file(not necessarily xml file) into the pom file.

My pom file looks like:

```
<project>...
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.5</version>
       <configuration>
         <username>${svn.username}</username>
         <password>${svn.pass}</password>`enter code here`
         <checkoutDirectory>${path}</checkoutDirectory>
         <skipCheckoutIfExists/>
       </configuration>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>checkout_a</id>
           <configuration>
             <connectionUrl>I want to get the url and other properties from a xml file</connectionUrl>
             <checkoutDirectory>${path}</checkoutDirectory>
           </configuration>
           <phase>process-resources</phase>
             <goals>
               <goal>checkout</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
  </plugin>     
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: How this is related to ClearCase?

Comment: i need to checkout sources from svn and clear case also

Comment: This question is a Maven issue, asking how to load an external properties file. I'd suggest you accept Ryan Stewart's answer. The Properties plug-in is the solution you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use the properties plugin to [read pom properties from a properties file](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html). If not a properties file, then you'll probably need to use [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home), write some groovy code to parse the file, and then update the pom properties yourself.

Comment: can u please explain how to use the plugin

Comment: Which one? Usage of the properties plugin is described pretty thoroughly [on that website](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html), and for GMaven, you'll need to know or learn some groovy.

Comment: i require a maven project to the task

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: How to use the plugin is described on the website: http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to declare the svn url as a property in your pom.xml, as illustrated in [this (french) article](http://www.touilleur-express.fr/2010/06/17/jpa-et-maven-gerer-2-persistence-xml-distincts/) ([translated here](http://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.touilleur-express.fr/2010/06/17/jpa-et-maven-gerer-2-persistence-xml-distincts/)).

```
<connection>scm:svn:http://my.svn.server/trunk</connection>
```

However, like this [thread illustrates](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/read-scm-connection-url-using-svn-info-td105350.html), you cannot get the "current" repo (through `svn info`).

And you can see [here for an scm ClearCase URL](http://maven.apache.org/scm/clearcase.html):

```
scm:clearcase<delimiter>[viewName]<delimiter>[loadCommand]<delimiter>[VOBName]<delimiter>[streamName]<delimiter>/main/fooBar/LATEST
```

Comment: thanks for ur replies 
but
sorry i dont want to hardcode the connection url
the url should be taken from an external file such as xml,properties files etc ... into the pom.xml
otherwise is there any maven code which will do the same

Comment: there is no answer to the link u provided http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/read-scm-connection-url-using-svn-info-td105350.html

Comment: @pavan: the fact that there is no answer to the thread I mentioned is, for me, a strong indication there is *not* a way to dynamically get the url in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: @pavan: so a possible solution would to write a **wrapper** to maven, which would get your info, modify the `pom.xml`, and call maven as usual.

Comment: i'm new to maven. can u please explain me how to write a wrapper in maven and modify pom.xml?

Comment: @paven: it is just a shell script which would change the pom.xml in order to hard code the repo address, and then call maven. So it doesn't require to know much about maven, just about basic scripting (replacing a line in a file).